# Change Video on Click - Inside of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html5-video

I'm trying to simply change the html, a video element in this case, of a div container.

I'm a noob at this so please bear with me.

Instantly i'm getting a syntax error on the 2nd line of javascript in dreamweaver.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres my code,

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Change Video on Click</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pageContainer">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#cf_onclick").toggle(
        function(){$(this).html("video source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1024" height="768" preload="auto" autoplay='autoplay' loop='loop');}, 
        function(){$(this).html("video source src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1024" height="768" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop");}
    ).click();
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a syntax error. Either escape your quotes or use a single quote for the function and double quotes for attribute values.

```
$(this).html('video source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1024" height="768" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"');
```

Examples:

```
$(this).html('<div id="blah"/>');
$(this).html("<div id=\"blah\"/>");
```

Comment: so fo you mean like this?   $("#cf_onclick").toggle(
        function(){$(this).html('<video source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1024" height="768" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"/>');}, 
        function(){$(this).html('<video source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="1024" height="768" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"/>');}
    ).click();